# Is there any reference to April's Fools Day jokes in Harry Potter's world?

Tags: harry-potter

There are many jokes in the Harry Potter books but is there any joke done as April's Fools Day joke?

Comment: Fred and George were born on April Fools Day. Does that count?

Comment: @alexwlchan I guess so but does it count as an in-universe joke? :)

Comment: Yes, there are.  April Fool's Day was the day when Harry's unnamed uncle was first transformed into a monkey named Bob by the evil wizard Moldyvort.                                                                       Hah!  Got you, didn't I?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, there's a brief mention in Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire. Apparently it's a known tradition in the Wizarding world.

> ‘No wonder they were glad to get shot of him at the Ministry, **did you
> hear him telling Seamus what he did to that witch who shouted “boo”
> behind him on April Fools’ Day?** And when are we supposed to read up on
> resisting the Imperius Curse with everything else we’ve got to do?’
>
> <sub><sup>***HP and the Goblet of Fire - Chapter 15: Beauxbatons and Durmstrang***</sup></sub>

---

Moving down the canon, there was also a mention of an April Fool's Day prank in the [Gamecube version of Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdP5-1v1fqg).

> Stinkitus is a magical disease provoked by breathing the noxious green
> gas left when one explodes a Stink Pellet. On April 1st, 1979,
> approximately five-hundred cases of Stinkitus were reported throughout
> London. This happened because 42-year old Caractacus Phelps dropped no
> less than eight hundred Stink Pellets from the roof of the Daily
> Prophet building in Diagon Alley.
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter Wiki - Stinkitus](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Stinkitus)</sup></sub>

Comment: This answer has been edited twice in the very short time it took me to read it. I saw it evolve, take form.. it was beautiful.

Comment: @Kalissar - You get 5 mins to edit without it showing as an "official" edit. I missed the cutoff and that makes me slightly sad.

Comment: Probably not the place to discuss this, but then why not just wait until you're happy with your answer before posting it ?

Comment: @Kalissar Because REP. Post an answer before anyone else does and it's likely to get more upvotes. Right, Richard? ;-)

Comment: @Kalissar - I tend to edit on the fly. Once it's an answer, I usually post it but I'll probably make several sets of revisions, then go away for a bit, then see if any of the comments have suggested other bits of information to add/research, then edit it again later. For example, I've just noticed that the game mentioned doesn't have a link.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yes. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem